# Colours Compiling Differently Than Defined Online

Tags: color, compiling

I am creating a poster using `baposter` and have set my background to fade from one colour to another. I have used a defined colour from latexcolor.com but when I compile document the colours turn out differently from the site. My code for the colour is:

```
\definecolor{caribbeangreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.8, 0.6}
```

Color comparision between online & my document:

[image: Color comparison between online & my document]

Is there an easy fix for this? I also have compiled the same document on a mac computer and it produces the colours correctly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide small but complete document, which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Have you tried \definecolor{caribbeangreen}{RGB}{0,204,153} ? Or \definecolor{caribbeangreen}{HTML}{00CC99}? Or the other color models? Because i am not convinced that the Hex value matches the values you entered...

Comment: @Sango: 205/255 = 0.8, and 153/255 = 0.6 actually.

Comment: In the attached PNG, color-picker on GIMP suggests that the caribbean green block is indeed 00CC99, but the left edge of the blue stripe generated is around 2A9AAB. // Since you mentioned that the document compiled on a Mac gets the correct colors, you should perhaps include more details about your set-up. What is the OS, what installation of TeX, has the TeX distribution been updated recently, what's the package version for `baposter` and the dependencies.

Comment: @WillieWong fascinating... then my gut feeling about numbers was off. Sorry. But anyway, maybe the package does something different depending on the model. And also, yes a MWE would help a lot.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `baposter` loads the `xcolor` package with the `cmyk` option. This means that all colours (even those defined in RGB) are converted to CMYK using the very simplistic formulas from the `xcolor` package.

The `baposter` background is created using a `pgf` shading. Before `pgf` version 3.3 these shadings were always in RGB (probably your Mac is using an old version of `pgf`). But since `pgf` version 3.3, `pgf` will output shadings in CMYK if the current `xcolor` colour model is CMYK.

The easiest way to fix the issue is to use

```
\documentclass{baposter}
\selectcolormodel{rgb}
```

Here's a MWE showing the background output using an RGB shading and the difference between your `caribbeangreen` when output with a CMYK `xcolor` model and when output with an RGB `xcolor` model:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,landscape]{baposter}
\selectcolormodel{rgb}
\definecolor{caribbeangreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.8, 0.6}
\begin{document}
\begin{poster}
  {bgColorOne=caribbeangreen, bgColorTwo=white, columns=2}
  {}{}{}{}
  \begin{posterbox}
    [headershade=plain, boxshade=plain, textborder=none,
    headerColorOne=caribbeangreen, boxColorOne=white]
    {RGB}
      Hello World.
  \end{posterbox}
  \selectcolormodel{cmyk}
  \begin{posterbox}
    [headershade=plain, boxshade=plain, textborder=none,
    headerColorOne=caribbeangreen, boxColorOne=white, column=1]
    {CMYK}
      Hello World.
  \end{posterbox}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]